# Confusion in solving $\frac{dy}{dt}=iy$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, complex-numbers

We would like to find real solutions to $\frac{dy}{dt}=iy$. We assume that all solutions will be of the form $y=e^{ct}$. Here, we have $c=i$, which gives $y=e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$. By taking the real and imaginary parts, we have two real solutions $y=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$. But this means $\cos t=i\sin t$ and $-\sin t = i\cos t$. If we square the latter on both sides and add $\cos^2t$, we get $\sin^2t+\cos^2t=0$, which is impossible. Do we have any explanation on this?

Comment: Why do you think you can take the real part and use it to solve $\frac{dy}{dt}=iy$?

Comment: If $y$ is a real-valued function, the left side of your equation is also a real-valued function, but the right side is purely imaginary. The only way this can happen is if $y\equiv0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither $y=\cos t$ nor $y=\sin t$ are solutions of the given equation, so there is no paradox.

---

If you want to, you can see the complex equation as a system of two real ones,

$$y'=u'+iv'=iy=i(u+iv)$$ which decomposes as

$$\begin{cases}u'=-v,\\v'=u.\end{cases}$$

You can solve it by eliminating $v$ with $$u''=-v'=-u$$ giving the general solution

$$u=a\cos t+b\sin t.$$

And $v$ follows by

$$v=-u'=a\sin t-b\cos t.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. It took me a while to understand it. Now I see that we can only have complex solutions, except $y=0$ as @symplectomorphic mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

> By taking the real and imaginary parts, we have two real solutions $y=\cos t$ and $y=\sin t$

Why do you think the real part of the solution is a solution to the original equation?

This is only true if the original equation only has real coefficients (yours, obviously, doesn't).

Comment: My textbook says I can take the real and imaginary parts of the complex solutions if I want the real solutions. Now I know I cannot do that in this case. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @W.Zhu Your textbook says you can do that **if the original differential equation has only real coefficients**.